# Put result into a named cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is some code...

```
function BUTTON1()
{
  // Point this at the spreadsheet we are using
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Pull some data from the spredsheet
  var value1 = sheet.getRange('Value_1');
  var value2 = sheet.getRange('Value_2');
  // Do some basic calculations...
  var result2 = value1 + value2;
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------
  // So how do I put the value 'result2' into the spreadsheet named cell
  // called 'Result_2' ???
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------
 }
```

I have named cells... "*Value_1*", "*Value_2*", "*Result_1*", and "*Result_2*" I am simply trying to have the user click a button (drawing) which calls this test routine (BUTTON1)... it should then pull the two values and simply add them together in the variable 'result2'.

**I got that part...**

Now HOW do I push the data in '***result2***' to the spreadsheet named cell '***Result_2***'???

Answer (score 1):

To edit values in any cell you would want to use the .Value attribute, which works on the Range() and Cells() commands (which are some of the most popular commands for manipulating data).

Then to use use a specific named range you can simply add it into the chosen command, such as in the below example.

```
Range("Result_2").Value = result2
```

**EDIT**
Apologies, I've just seen that you are using google sheets. I've never used them but a quick google led me to think that you can set a value by using the following (or a variation of it):

```
sheet.getRange(Result_2).setValue(result2);
```

Comment: Whether this is correct or not is up to the OP. However, a short paragraph or even a sentence or two by way of explanation would have gone a long way into making this a great answer.

Comment: You may need to use 'Result_2' rather than Result_2, hewre's the page I looked at http://www.faqssys.info/how-to-get-google-spreadsheets-to-auto-update-a-reference-to-another-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out... WHoo!

```
function BUTTON1()
{
  // Point this at the spreadsheet we are using
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Pull some data from that spredsheet
  var value1 = sheet.getRange("Value_1").getValue();
  var value2 = sheet.getRange("Value_2").getValue();
  var result2 = value1 + value2;
  var location  = sheet.getRange("Result_2");
  location.setValue(result2);
}
```

You have to not only say getRange but you also have to tack on getValue... and don't forget to put in the "()" or it fails.

Jerry